# Логирование Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, логирование

Я создаю проект, используя командную строку Cordova. В качестве целевой платформы для сборки указываю только андроид, приложение на устройстве запускается, всё отлично. Но как увидеть сообщения, которые создаются с помощью метода `console.log()`? Например, после создания проекта исходный файл Project/www/js/index.js выглядит следующим образом:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

Я предполагаю, что строка `console.log('Received Event: ' + id);` должна выводить сообщение "Received Event: ..." в консоль, но я не могу его увидеть. 
Я добавила плагин `cordova-plugin-console`, но сообщения всё равно не видны. 
При запуске из командной строки пакетного файла log

```
Project\platforms\android\cordova>log
```

в консоль сыплется много сообщений, но увидеть сообщения "Received Event: ..." я среди них я не могу (возможно, потому что сообщений слишком много, но установить уровень логирования (debug, error и т.д.) я также не могу.

Я добавила в переменную среды PATH %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools\ и %ANDROID_HOME%\tools\, пыталась увидеть сообщения через adb:

```
adb logcat CordovaLog:D  *:S
```

но это также ни к чему не привело, в консоли после этой команды я вижу только две строки:

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
```

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться: могу ли я увидеть это сообщение ("Received Event: ..."), и что мне нужно для этого сделать?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: ionic serve например

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да , можете. У меня всё работает без плагина. Я использую Android Device Monitor (у меня лежит в `{android_sdk_path}\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64\monitor.exe`), фильтр `tag:Console`.

Особенность android - `console.log` принимает только один аргумент, т.е. `console.log(1,2)` вы увидите только 1. Кроме того, обьекты и массивы, как в консоли браузера вы тоже не увидите (я использую `JSON.stringify`, но это не панацея, т.к. при ислледовании системных объектов легко можно поймать ошибку про converting circular structures to json).

Вот как у меня это выглядит:

[image: Вот как у меня это выглядит]
Фильтр:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прошу прошения, но как именно вы используете Android Device Monitor (не для эмулятора, а для подключённого устройства)?

Comment: Добавил скрины. У вас он не видит устройство?

Comment: Всё получилось, спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: Еще можно в PowerShell логировать вот так: `adb logcat | Select-String (adb shell ps | findstr io.cordova.hellocordova).Split("", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]` (подставьте app id вместо `io.cordova.hellocordova`).